# What's the meaning of 'no less applicable to '?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> *Competition* seems no less applicable to a one-time event than the word *contest* (observe how this reporter talks about [the outdoor cooking competition](http://www.boston.com/yourtown/news/dorchester/2012/08/dorchester_chefs_claim_top_pri.html)).
>   <sub>Source: [word choice - "Contest" vs. "competition" - English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/77827/11482)</sub>

In the above sentence, what does the 'no less applicable to' mean?

Comment: Note that in the original post, it wasn't about a "word contest". It was about the word *contest*.

Answer (score 1):

The preposition used with an adjective is usually the same as the preposition used with the adjective's verbal form.

We can **apply** a label **to** something.

If it is a suitable label (the can of beans is labelled "Beans") then we can say that

The label is **applicable to** it.

applicable to =  can (truthfully) be applied to.

When we say that *a label can be applied to something* or that a label is *applicable*, we mean that the label is correct or accurate or true.

No less = equally (or perhaps even greater)

Answer (score 0):

> definition of applicable (from [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/applicable?s=t))
>
> adjective
>
> 1. applying or capable of being applied; relevant; suitable;

We should also note that to apply means to "put into use".
Less is just a quantifier, and "no" is a negation.

So this simply means that the competition seems to be equally suitable to a one-time event, and to the word contest.
The competition is not any less competent and able to perform in a one-time event than it is in a word contest.